# Jacobson radical of endomorphisms of direct sum of indecomposables

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$\newcommand\End{\operatorname{End}}$Let $A$ be a commutative $k$-algebra and $M=N_1\oplus N_2$ be a decomposition of a finite-length $A$-module $M$ into two non-isomorphic indecomposable summands. Consider the endomorphism ring $E=\End(M)$ of $M$. What is $J(E)$?

I would expect that it is of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}J(\End(N_1)) & *\\ * & J(\End(N_2))\end{pmatrix},$$

but neither am I totally convinced nor can I prove this. At least, $J(\End(N_i))\subseteq J(E)$ as follows: let $a\in J(\End(N_1))$, take $\begin{pmatrix}x_1&*\\{}*&*\end{pmatrix}$ arbitrarily and choose $s$ such that $(1-ax)s=1$.

$$\left[\begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}a\\&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2\\{}*&*\end{pmatrix}\right]\begin{pmatrix}s & sax_2\\&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

However, this neither shows that $J(\End(N_i))$ exhaust the diagonal entries, nor that any matrix with only off-diagonal entries is contained in $J(E)$. Is this even true?

Comment: The thing to know is that $End(M\oplus N)\cong\begin{bmatrix}End(M)&Hom(N, M)\\Hom(M,N)&End(N)\end{bmatrix}$.  Now if $M$ and $N$ are *irreducible* and nonisomorphic, this would imply the off-diagonals are zero, and that the ring is the product of the two endomorphism rings, and the radical is the product of radicals. However, I don't know how this works with *indecomposable* modules.  Can you have nonzero, non-surjective homomorphisms between distinct indecomposables?

Comment: @rschwieb Sure, consider $A=k[1\mathop{\leftrightarrows}\limits_\beta^a2]/(ba)$  and the indecomposable projectives $Ae_1$, $Ae_2$. Then $Ae_1\xrightarrow{\cdot b}Ae_2\xrightarrow{\cdot a} Ae_1$ are two non-zero non-isomorphisms. However, their *composition* is zero. The point is: if $M, N$ are of finite length, I'd assume that all off-diagonal-entries are zero divisors. Is this valid?

Comment: Messed up the labels; sorry. But I think the example is clear.

Comment: Your line of thought is out of my experience!  But i trust it, I guess it is certainly possible.  But certainly there are examples that show the off-diagonal elements can be zero for some modules. For example, $A=k=\mathbb Z$ and $M=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$ for distinct primes $p,q$.  (That's an example using two *irreducible* modules, of course.)

Comment: @rschwieb Of course the modules can be in such way that the off-diagonal entries are always zero. But I think this is not necessary to assume, is it? Can't I assume that for any $a\in\hom(M, N)$ and $b\in\hom(N, M)$ that $ab$ is nilpotent? Because then I'd say that $\begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\a&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b'&b\\{}*&*\end{pmatrix}$ always is a unit with explicit inverse.

Comment: I'm not saying you should *assume* that, I'm offering it as an example of (what I thought was) your conjecture about the description of the radical not being accurate. I guess you might mean something else by "$\ast" than what I thought.

Comment: I have never thought about the nilpotency condition you're mentioning... perhaps it is true! I have never seen a description of the radical of $End(M\oplus N)$, so it would all be new to me.

Comment: @rschwieb Would you mind having a look at my answer, whether I missed something?

Comment: Sorry: I don't have time budgeted to give it a thorough reading.

Comment: @rschwieb Okay, then I just leave it as is. Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\End{\operatorname{End}}\newcommand\Aut{\operatorname{Aut}}\newcommand\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}\newcommand{\Mtx}[1]{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)}$Let $M$ be a module of finite length
    with a decomposition $M=L_1^{n_1}\oplus\dotsb\oplus L_k^{n_k}$ into sums of pairwise non-isomorphic indecomposable modules $L_i$.
    Then $J(\End(M))$ is generated by the Jacobson radicals of the $\End(L_i)$'s
    and all morphisms between distinct $L_i$'s.

*Proof.*
    It suffices to consider $M=L_1^{n_1}\oplus L_2^{n_2}$.
    It has endomorphism ring
    $$
  \End(M)=\begin{pmatrix}\End(L_1)^{n_1\times n_1} & \Hom(L_2, L_1)^{n_1\times n_2}\\\Hom(L_1, L_2)^{n_2\times n_1}&\End(L_2)^{n_2\times n_2}\end{pmatrix}.
 $$
    For simplicity, assume that $n_1=n_2=1$;
    for the off-diagonal blocks, the general case follows by extending the matrix by zeroes as appropriate,
    and for the diagonal blocks, the general case follows from the fact that $J(S^{n\times n})=J(S)^{n\times n}$ for full matrix rings.

We claim that matrices with entries only on the diagonal are in $J(\End(M))$ if and only if
    the entries are in the respective Jacobson radicals.
    Consider $\Mtx{1\\&1}-\Mtx{a\\&0}\Mtx{b' & b\\{}*&*}$ and choose $s$ such that $(1-ab')s=1$.
    Then
    $$
  \left[\begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}a\\&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b' & b\\{}*&*\end{pmatrix}\right]\begin{pmatrix}s & ab\\&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\end{pmatrix},
 $$
    so $[\cdots]$ is a unit.
    Conversely, if $$\left[\begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}a\\&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b' & b\\{}*&*\end{pmatrix}\right]\begin{pmatrix}s & *\\z&*\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\end{pmatrix},$$
    it follows that $z=0$ and $(1-ab')s=1$.

We claim that any matrix with entries only in the off-diagonal blocks belongs to $J(\End(M))$.
    Let $a\in\Hom(L_1,L_2)$, which corresponds to $\Mtx{0\\a&0}\in \End(M)$.
    Since $M$ is of finite length, so is $L_1$.
    Consider an arbitrary matrix $\Mtx{b' & b\\{}*&*}\in\End(M)$ with $b\in\Hom(L_2, L_1)$.
    Fitting's lemma implies that the composition $ba$ is either an isomorphism or nilpotent.
    If it were an isomorphism, $a$ would be an inclusion with retraction $b$,
    implying that $L_2$ contains a summand isomorphic to $L_1$
    and thus contradicting the assumption.
    Thus, $ab$ is nilpotent, say $(ab)^n=0$.
    $$
  \left[\begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}0\phantom{b'}\\a&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b' & b\\{}*&*\end{pmatrix}\right]\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\(1+\dotsb+(ab)^{n-1})ab' & 1+\dotsb+(ab)^{n-1}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\end{pmatrix},
 $$
    so $[\cdots]$ is a unit.

Recall that no automorphism of $L_i$ factors through a distinct $L_j$,
    and since $L_i$ is of finite length, $\End(L_i)$ is a local ring with maximal ideal consisting of all non-automorphisms.
    Let $J$ be the ideal generated by matrices with entries $\Mtx{J(\End(L_1))&*\\{}*&J(\End(L_2))}$.
    Thus the quotient $M/J=\Aut(L_1)^{n_1\times n_1}\oplus\Aut(L_2)^{n_2\times n_2}$ is a semisimple algebra.
    This shows that $J=J(\End(M))$.

Comment: In your first matrix equation above, do you want 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
s&sab\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}?
$$
This is a very nice answer, though!